# Why do I have Termux and Termux(failsafe)?

Tags: termux, f-droid

Why do I have two Termux applications, and what's the difference? This happened recently, after updating Termux I believe. I've installed Termux from F-Droid, and it mentions (failsafe) in the application name there. Cannnot see that in the Play Store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Termux (failsafe) is shown on the app drawer since the last update. When you update Termux to the latest version, it is also shown.

From this comment from [what is Termux (failsafe)?](https://github.com/termux/termux-app/issues/1101):

> We have made sessions auto-closeable, see #988 for more information.
>
> Auto-closeable sessions may put application into "denial-of-service" condition if user will mess with files like .bashrc - in such case access to files on internal storage will be completely lost. Thus we had to create a separate icon.
>
> It's very unlikely that we will remove it. Easy access to failsafe shell is mandatory but unfortunately there no other reliable variants that will work on all Android versions.

Also based in [this comment](https://github.com/termux/termux-app/issues/277#issuecomment-286309177) in Termux github:

> This creates a limited shell using only the Android system tools.

If for whatever reason Termux is unable to start, then use Termux failsafe.

Comment: Thanks. According to [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/termux/comments/bduqgq/what_is_termux_failsafe/el0uv96/) it won't be removed either, annoying. At least I have Nova Launcher to hide app icons.

Comment: Yes, for now one can only hide it or remove Termux (which is not a good solution).

Answer (score 0):

It's just like the recovery mode feature for your Termux environment.

See: [Termux Wiki - Recover a broken environment](https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Recover_a_broken_environment)

Answer (score 0):

**Scenario**

A new user just decided to change their default Termux shell to Fish instead of Bash. The easiest solution they came up with is to add these lines to `.bashrc` (`../usr/etc/bash.bashrc`)

```
fish
exit
```

It worked, but for some reason, they don't like Fish. They uninstalled/removed it and closed Termux without changing the contents of `.bashrc`. The next time they opened Termux, they saw this

```
The program fish is not installed. Install it by executing:
 pkg install fish

[Process completed (code 127) - press Enter]
```

Now, to fix this, they either need to **edit `.bashrc`** or **install Fish** again. For this, we need a shell that **doesn't run `.bashrc`**. Failsafe mode is the easiest and most helpful thing now.